# How do I stop UWP Camera requiring permission to the Microphone

Tags: c#, uwp, permissions, camera, mediacapture

So I am initialising a `MediaCapture` element in my UWP application on my Surface Pro device like so:

```
            // Create MediaCapture and its settings
            mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id,
                AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
                //StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                //PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo
            };

            // Initialize MediaCapture
            try
            {
                await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);
                ....
            }
```

at the line `InitializeAsync` the application asks for both camera and microphone capabilities.

Now I have no need for the Microphone capability as I am only capturing photos and many of my users deny access to the Microphone saying "Why do you need microphone access to take a photo"

I tested using the built in "Camera" app and denying permission to the Microphone on windows and this works perfectly.

I looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) and it says:

> InitializeAsync will launch a consent prompt to get the user's
>   permission for the app to access the microphone or camera

So is it possible to stop the app asking for Microphone permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve it pretty easily by changing the `StreamingCaptureMode` on the `MediaCaptureInitializationSettings` adding this line:

```
StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
```

so it became:

```
var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
     VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id,
     AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
     StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
};
```